# Consecutively filter rows satisfyingly if condition in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement, tidyverse

In R data frame `dt_df` I want to retain all the rows with values in the following sequence as a new data frame.
I can have `dt_diff` any numbers between -1 to 20.
Now, I want to start by `1` (the previous day) and check if `dt_diff` has `1`. If there is `1`, filter all the rows with `1` in `dt_diff` retain this as a new data frame and stop processing, if there is not `1` check if there is `2`, if there is `2` retain all rows with `2` as a new data frame and stop processing and so on until `20`. If there are not any values between 1 to 20, then check if there is `0`, if there is `0`, retain rows with `0` as a new data frame, and stop processing. If there is no `0` or any values between 1 to 20 then check if there is `-1` and retain all the rows with `-1` as a new data frame. How can I achieve this? Here is sample data and unsuccessful `for` loop with `if` condition.

```
dt_df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(12241, 12241, 12257, 12257,
  12257, 12257, 12257, 12257, 12257, 12257, 12259), class = "Date"),
  ref_date = structure(c(12259, 12259, 12259, 12259, 12259,
    12259, 12259, 12259, 12259, 12259, 12259), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA,
      -11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
dt_df
dt_df$dt_diff <- as.numeric(dt_df$ref_date -dt_df$date)
pbl_dt_seq <- seq(-1, 20, 1)
pbl_dt_seq

for (i in 1:length(pbl_dt_seq)) {
    i <- 2 # start with number 1
     if(any(dt_df$dt_diff) == i ){
      retain_dt <- dt_df %>%
           filter(dt_diff == i)
      retain_dt
      break
    }
  if(any(dt_df$dt_diff) ==i+1 ){
      retain_dt <-dt_df%>%
        filter(dt_diff == i+1)
      retain_dt
      break
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does `split(dt_df, dt_df$dt_diff)` do what you want?

Comment: No, because in this example I want to retain only `dt_df$dt_diff =2' as a new data frame and ignore others.  But this `2` can vary and not sure how to retain as in the sequence mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the sequence in the order that you want to check the values so first 1 to 20 and then 0 and -1. `arrange` the data so that the data is ordered by the  correct sequence and select rows which is similar to first `dt_diff` in the dataframe.

```
librayr(dplyr)
pbl_dt_seq <- c(1:20, 0, -1)

dt_df %>%
  arrange(match(dt_diff, pbl_dt_seq)) %>%
  filter(dt_diff == first(dt_diff))

#   date       ref_date   dt_diff
#  <date>     <date>       <dbl>
#1 2003-07-24 2003-07-26       2
#2 2003-07-24 2003-07-26       2
#3 2003-07-24 2003-07-26       2
#4 2003-07-24 2003-07-26       2
#5 2003-07-24 2003-07-26       2
#6 2003-07-24 2003-07-26       2
#7 2003-07-24 2003-07-26       2
#8 2003-07-24 2003-07-26       2
```